# Creating a List of Dictionary Values with data from a file

Tags: python, tuples, readfile

I have a method that inputs a path/directory to a folder and a filename. I need to retrieve the data from the specified file name in the folder and create a `LIST of DICTIONARIES`.

PART of an example file is below:

```
VLSEGEWQLVLHVWAKVEADVAGHGQDILIRLFKSHPETLEKFDRFKHLKTEAEMKASEDLKK

1 137 0 8 7.887

10 127 0 8 7.388

10 130 0 8 5.087

11 131 0 8 5.400

10 134 0 8 4.770
```

The FIRST LINE of each file should be ignored. Then, the first two numbers in each row will be the values assigned to key value 'pairs', the `0` and the `8` are ignored, and the last number is the value assigned to 'distance'
this is done to each row in the file, with each row being a new dict.

So the output should look like

```py
output = [
   {"pairs": (1,137), "distance": 7.887},

   {"pairs": (10,127), "distance": 7.388},

   {"pairs": (10,130), "distance": 5.087},

   {"pairs": (11,131), "distance": 5.400},

   {"pairs": (10,134), "distance": 4.770},

]
```

I am not sure how to approach this problem, whether its how to read the file and each row of the file. What I have so far is pretty basic. I haven't implemented creating the list of dictionaries. I tried to start out with the basic and reading each row and copying the data but the output is an empty list. **PLEASE NOTE THAT THIS SEGMENT OF CODE IS WRONG AND ONLY WHAT I TRIED.**

```
def get_rr(self, file_name, path):
    my_lst = []
    #takes every file in folder and put in files list
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        #splits the file name into file name and its extension
        with open(os.path.join(path,f)) as file_object:
                line = file_object.readline()
                while 1:
                    line = file_object.readline().rstrip()
                    if line == "":
                        break
                    my_lst.append(line)

        return my_lst
```

**MY QUESTION: HOW CAN I PROGRAM TO MAKE THE OUTPUT LOOK LIKE BELOW:**

```py
output = [
   {"pairs": (1,137), "distance": 7.887},

   {"pairs": (10,127), "distance": 7.388},

   {"pairs": (10,130), "distance": 5.087},

   {"pairs": (11,131), "distance": 5.400},

   {"pairs": (10,134), "distance": 4.770},

]
```

Answer (score 1):

comprehensions are very handy. Also, you probably don't need the distinction between filepath and name, the OS will handle that for you. With that in mind something like this should work

```
def get_ss(self, path):
    with open(path) as file:
        lines = list(file)[2:]
        return [{"pairs":tuple(map(int, words[:2])), "distance":float(words[-1])} for words in (line[:-1].split() for line in lines if line.strip())]
```

Comment: Strange, it works fine for me. Could you provide the full error